# Ruby Rails Gems question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install a Jabber Client called PSI on Linux Redmine installation.

So, I have done the following:

```
$ gem install xmpp4r

$ cd {REDMINE_ROOT}
$ git clone git://github.com/mszczytowski/redmine_messenger.git vendor/plugins/redmine_messenger

$ vim config/messenger.yml  #( <- Haven't set this up yet.)

$ rake db:migrate_plugins
```

When I do the rake it tells me:

```
-bash-3.2$ rake db:migrate_plugins
(in /home/username/redmine)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- xmpp4r
```

The gems seem to install properly and everything.  Just not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to mention it in `config/environment.rb`:

```
config.gem "xmpp4r"
```